# How to find if a tag is open

Tags: html, tags

Is there software out there to check a .html file to see if all the tags are correctly closed?

I tried `TagCheck` but this did not work as i put my file and ran it and got no errors, then i added a `<tr>` tag with no closing tag and ran again and still got no errors

So is there another software out there to do this or any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**notepad++**](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) code editor software. You can check easily with it.

Also check your HTML by pasting it in http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input to validate it online.

http://img210.imageshack.us/img210/8066/testjn.png

Comment: how do you mean you can check it easily with notepad++, how can you check if the tags are closed using it?

Comment: If you double click on the tag (you want to check) it will turn it into green color and will also show the corresponding closing tag in green color.

Comment: @Hip Hip Array: See example image in my answer above.

Comment: i no the above answer might be a better one(i didn't look at it too much) but as it was only one .html file that i was looking at this worked perfectly for me :)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_upload) and all the [other validators](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tools/) out there

Comment: the page that i am working on is not public yet, i am running on a localhost... does this accomidate for this?

Comment: Here you can directly enter the HTML source: http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: +1 for the answer... But I am also using tapestry in my html page so this gave me 10 errors and 126 warnings :/

Comment: Or some browsers (some with plugins / extensions) also provide the option to just send the rendered HTML to the validator. All you have to do is press a button :).

Comment: Note that the validator won't for HTML (as opposed to XHTML) report the absence of a `</tr>` tag either, since they are optional tags.